# Redis - Handle Concurrent Reads And Writes

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm working with a Redis database where I often have to read a large set of data. However, while I'm in the process of reading, there could be another process concurrently writing to the same database, potentially altering the data that I'm trying to read.

This creates a problem for me, because when I initiate a read operation, I need the data snapshot to be consistent as of the moment the read starts, irrespective of any concurrent write operations.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to configure the reading process to retrieve the state of the data as it was at the start of the read operation, despite any concurrent writes that may happen during the read?
2. If not, is there a mechanism in Redis that can temporarily block write operations while a read is underway?

I’ve tried using transactions both for reading and writing but I noticed that the data I read is still being changed by the writing operation.
I also thought about using redlock but it doesn’t fit my needs because I want to allow concurrent reading.

Comment: Do you have a single instance of Redis or are you running in a clustered environment?

Comment: I need to support both single-node and clustered environment.

Comment: Is the data in a single key or multiple keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Redis Transactions** was the solution for me after all.
Redis transactions do "block" other operations while reading.

As the [official redis Transactions docs](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/) says:

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed sequentially. **A request sent by another client will never be served in the middle of the execution of a Redis Transaction**. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a single isolated operation.